# Acts passed in the UK affecting criminal justice under Blair

Tags: united-kingdom, reference-request

What is the best repository for researching acts that were passed in the UK under a certain government that affected a specific area of legislature? Is it necessary to trawl through all acts passed within the specific timeframe, or is there a more efficient method / are there any such catagorised listings available anywhere?

As an example, please see the title.

To generalise, can this be done for the US / other countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most legislation of western countries is in an online database - the UK's is http://www.legislation.gov.uk/; you can search this more or less as you wish.

Comment: I presume looking under UK Public General Acts would be the approriate umbrella for the question as posed?

Comment: @martin Yes, that's right.